# Groovy unexpected token: @ @ line

Tags: groovy

I am getting following error when i run groovy:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
C:\Users\kbekur\MuleStudio\workspace\GroovyTest\src\com\test\SQLGroovy.groovy: 3: unexpected token: @ @ line 3, column 2.
    @Grab(group='org.hsqldb', module='hsqldb', version='2.3.2')
    ^

1 error
```

And my code is:

```
@Grapes([
     @GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)
     @Grab(group='org.hsqldb', module='hsqldb', version='2.3.2')
])
import groovy.sql.Sql
def db = [url:'jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/testdb', user:'sa', password:'', driver:'org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver']
def sql = Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver)
println 'Some GR8 projects:'
sql.eachRow('select * from Persons') { row ->
    println "${row.lastname.padRight(10)} ($row.personid)"
}
```

After analysis, I have found that

```
You can't annotate a statement. 
You should put the grab annotation on an import, for instance.
```

I am not clear with above statement, what changes I need to make to fix compilation issue and load the jars.

I am referring the code from: [jars, system class loader](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/04/groovy-goodness-configuring-grape-to.html)

Comment: You need a comma before the `@Grab` after the `@GrabConfig`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a comma between the two items in the `@Grapes` list, ie:

```
@Grapes([
    @GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true),
    @Grab(group='org.hsqldb', module='hsqldb', version='2.3.2')
])
```

You can also remove the `@Grapes` part, to give just:

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)
@Grab(group='org.hsqldb', module='hsqldb', version='2.3.2')
```

(no comma is needed here, as they are no longer in a List)